# Can I filter options automatically on the Django Admin "add" page?

Tags: django, django-admin

Consider a Word-A-Day Django webapp that presents the user with a vocabulary word each day, with the difficulty of the word increasing from "common" on Monday to "obscure" on Friday.

The models in `models.py` look like this:

```
class WordADay(models.Model):
    """A vocabulary word and its assigned day"""

    date = models.DateField(
        help_text="The date to post the selected word"
    )
    word = models.ForeignKey(
        Words,
        help_text="The selected vocabulary word"
    )

class Word(models.Model):
    """Vocabulary words"""

    OBSCURITY_CHOICES = [(1,'Monday'),
                         (2,'Tuesday'),
                         (3,'Wednesday'),
                         (4,'Thursday'),
                         (5,'Friday')]

    word = models.CharField(
        max_length=32,
        help_text="A vocabulary word"
    )
    difficulty = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=OBSCURITY_CHOICES,
        help_text="How obscure the word is"
    )
```

On the Admin "add" page for the WordADay model, I want to be able to first select a day from the standard calendar selector for the 'date' field.  Once selected, I'd like the options in the drop-down selector for the 'word' field to be automatically filtered to only those instances of the Word model that have the correct difficulty, with "1" corresponding to a Monday date and "5" corresponding to a Friday date.  That is, I'd like to filter Foreign Key options according to the value selected for a different field.

For the sake of discussion, I can provide a skeleton `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import WordADay, Word
from django.db import models

@admin.register(WordADay)
class WordADayAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(Word)
class WordAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

though of course it's not complete because I don't know what to put in it.

After a couple of hours of digging through the documentation I found the [`list_filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) property, described as

> Set list_filter to activate filters in the right sidebar of the change list page of the admin

This isn't what I want; I want a filter on the "add" page, not the "change" page, and I don't want a sidebar, I want the filter to be automatic once the date is selected.

Is this possible without creating a new AdminSite from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not something that there is any built in functionality within the django-admin to do. However, you wouldn't have to quite go to the extents of creating a completely new admin site from scratch.

The best way to do this would be to use javascript to update the values of the relevant form values. You'll need to add an event listner on the change event of one of your inputs, and set it to update another one.

Because django-admin uses jquery in one or two places you have access to jquery for free, or it is relatively easy to do this with just plain javascript.

In terms of how you attach the javascript to this page you have two options:

1. load the javascript via your modelAdmin)

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('js/my_script.js', ) # this should be a file from your static directory
```

2. Extend the template.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "my_template.html"
```

then in `my_template.html`

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block %}
{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
  ... add your script here
{% endblock %}
```

The advantage of the second option is that you can alter your script based on values loaded in through context, but this might not be necessary.

Comment: I want to add this to the 'add' page, not the 'change' page.  Is it the same template (`change_form.html`) for both?

Comment: @DarienMarks There is an `add_form_template` property as well, but I believe if it is left unset, the `change_form_template` will be used.

Comment: Okay, thanks!  It'll take me a little while to implement this, I'll come back when I have results.

Comment: I can confirm that both approaches work.  I tried 2. initially, but as described in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205136/how-do-i-attach-a-listener-to-a-date-selection-in-the-django-admin#62205924) that you also answered, using a calendar selector in particular introduces extra JavaScript complications.  I ended up getting it to work more smoothly with method 1. applied to a new Widget.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're more than weclome :) Glad you got it working