# How do I attach a listener to a date selection in the Django admin?

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django admin page for a model with a `DateField` called 'date':

```
# models.py
class Article(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(
        help_text="Article publication date"
    )
```

```
# admin.py
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = "article_extension.html"
```

I've extended the Admin add/change template for this model to include JavaScript to execute when a date is selected.

In the Admin add/change page, the default widget for this field is a text  element accompanied by a calendar selector.  The page source does not show any code for the selector, so the only thing I can attach JavaScript to is the input box:

```
<input type="text" ... id="id_date">
```

In the template's JavaScript, I've attached an EventListener for 'input' events on this input box:

```
# article_extension.html
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block extrahead %}
 block.super 
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var dateInput = document.getElementById("id_date");
    dateInput.addEventListener('input', dateListener);

    function dateListener() {
        console.log("date event recognized");
    }
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I then select a date from the calender selector, the contents of the input box change to reflect the selected date, but the EventListener doesn't fire.  If I manually type something into the input box, however, the EventListener fires and "date event recognized" shows up in the console.  Evidently, when the calendar is used to put content in the input box, this isn't recognized as "input".

How can I attach an EvenListener to either the input box or the calendar to fire when a date is selected from the calendar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why does your current solution not work?

The reason why this isn't working quite as you expect is that the django-admin date-time field is already run by a whole load of javascript. It is not a 'native' date-time input.

The `input` event will be fired whenever the element's value is changed by a user interaction. If the value is changed programatically, by another javascript function, the input event is **not** fired.

When you select a date from the calendar, this is what is happening. The value of the input is updated, but the input event is not fired.

### How can I fix it?

There are 3 solutions that come to mind:

#### Option 1

Use a different widget. There are a whole heap of date selectors out there, some of which I am sure will have an easy API to add a call-back for when the value is changed. I don't know a good one off the top of my head, but google will be your friend here.

Options 2 and 3 involve using the current widget. If we dig a bit in the code, we see that there are 2 js files that are loaded that are important for this widget:

- `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/calendar.js`
- `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/admin/DateTimeShortcuts.js`

After a bit of digging about in there you'll see that there's a function called `handleCalendarCallback` in `DateTimeShortcuts`. This is the function that set's the value.

```
handleCalendarCallback: function(num) {
    var format = get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS')[0];
    // the format needs to be escaped a little
    format = format.replace('\\', '\\\\')
        .replace('\r', '\\r')
        .replace('\n', '\\n')
        .replace('\t', '\\t')
        .replace("'", "\\'");
    return function(y, m, d) {
        DateTimeShortcuts.calendarInputs[num].value = new Date(y, m - 1, d).strftime(format);
        DateTimeShortcuts.calendarInputs[num].focus();
        document.getElementById(DateTimeShortcuts.calendarDivName1 + num).style.display = 'none';
    };
},
```

#### Option 2

Make your own widget that uses a new version of the above file with that one function edited a bit. It would look something like this:

```
class AdminDateWidget(forms.DateInput):
    class Media:
        js = [
            'admin/js/calendar.js',
            'admin/js/admin/MyVersionOfDateTimeShortcuts.js',
        ]

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, format=None):
        attrs = {'class': 'vDateField', 'size': '10', **(attrs or {})}
        super().__init__(attrs=attrs, format=format)
```

You could then use that widget for the relevant fields and you're edited code would run. Unfortunately because that file is a static file and not a template you can't use inheritance, so you would have to copy and paste the whole thing and then edit that one function.

#### Option 3

You'll notice that after the value is updated, `.focus()` is called, and so we could make use of that and attach an event listener to the focus event. Of course we'd only want something to happen if the value has actually changed, so we'd need to do something like this:

```
var dateValue;
window.onload = function() {
    var dateInput = document.getElementById("id_date");
    dateInput.addEventListener('focus', dateListener);

    function dateListener(event) {
        if (dateValue === event.target.value) {
            return
        }
        dateValue = event.target.value;
        // put the stuff you actually want to happen here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for another amazing answer.  I never would have identified the relevant JS files or the `handleCalendarCallback` function without your help.  I went with Option 2; it was fairly challenging, but it works!

Comment: It looks like 'focus' is fired when the date-selector is first clicked, but focus does not seem to fire again after a new date is chosen since the date values do not differ until the next time the date-picker is clicked on.  I have the id set on a div containing the form form field. <div id="time_filter" class="form-group col-md-2  mb-0">
     {{ form.time_filter|as_crispy_field }}
    </div>
Any thoughts on getting this solution to work?